# pianobarfly - stopped working

Tags: pandora

I was using pianobarfly and it no longer works, it appears the protocol was updated again.  Does anyone have any information regarding this?  The source hasn't changed since February, so I'm wondering what else to try.  The source for pianobar has changed and is quite different from what I have.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ghuntley/pianobarfly

Try the latest version; if that doesn't work, post an issue to our GitHub repository under the Issues tab.

Comment: please expand your answer.

Comment: @ghuntley: He oviously knows where to find your software, but can you actually help him? This link by itself has no value.

Answer (score 1):

[Pianobar](http://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar/) was just updated to support the updated protocol. It should work once the developers for pianobarfly merge the new libpiano into pianobarfly.

**EDIT**: Since you are saying that pianobarfly hasn't been updated since February. Just wait. Updates can sometimes take a long time to come out. If you aren't the patient type, maybe it's time to find a different solution.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping I was looking at an old version.

Comment: Yeah, usually if it has been longer than a year, you can consider it no longer in active development. If you can get an 'unstable' version of the program, you may want to try that.

Comment: And, also. I was looking at a [forum post about it](http://www.hak5.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=15775&st=20) and it was last updated on the 15th of September. So it is probably still in active development.